# How to get the number of bits of usize in older version of Rust?

Tags: rust

In 2022, I sometimes have to use Rust 1.42.0 (released in 2020) in remote environment.

How to get the number of bits of `usize` in that old version of Rust?

I once encountered a similar problem where I wanted to access the max value of `usize` but found `usize::MAX` doesn't exist in Rust 1.42.0. At that time, I found `std::usize::MAX` had already existed in 1.42.0. However, inconsistently, `std::usize::BITS` doesn't exist.

|  | Newer Rust | Rust 1.42.0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| max value | `usize::MAX` (Rust 1.43.0 or newer) | `std::usize::MAX` or `usize::max_value()` |
| min value | `usize::MIN` (Rust 1.43.0 or newer) | `std::usize::MIN` or `usize::min_value()` |
| # of bits | `usize::BITS` (Rust 1.53.0 or newer) | ***None*** of `std::usize::BITS` or `usize::bits_value()` exists. |

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no built-in simple method like `usize::BITS` or `usize::bits_value()`.

You have to use a relatively low-level operation to directly calculate the number of bits:

```rust
let bits = std::mem::size_of::<usize>() * 8;
```

(However, note `usize::BITS` is of type `u32` while `size_of()` returns `usize`.)

According to the related pull request ([*Add associated constant BITS to all integer types #76492*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/76492)), it seems this inconvenience is why `usize::BITS` is added in Rust 1.53.0 in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean `usize::BITS` is `u32`? Because `MAX` being anything but `usize` doesn't make sense.